# Converting float value to 2 decimal places in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a field on my database called `productivity`(float) which divides `work_time`(float) by `total_time`(float). it work but the output shows up like 0.727273 instead of 0.72. Is there a way in Laravel to fix this?

my controller:

```
$energy->productivity = $request->input('work_time') / ($request->input('admin_time') + $request->input('driving_time') + $request->input('work_time'));:
```

my view:

```
 <td>{{$data->productivity}}</td>
```

Comment: you can use as `<td>{{ number_format($data->productivity, 2) }}</td>`

Comment: Do you need rounding or just 2 digits? with rounding 0.727273 is `0.73` without `0.72`? Usually rounding seems to be the correct way. Or is it specified to just show last 2 digits?

Answer (score 1):

```
round($data->productivity, 2)
```

Output: 0.73

```
sprintf('%0.2f', $data->productivity)
```

Output: 0.72

Round function will round 0.727273 to 0.73. If you need to just take 2 digits you can use
`sprintf('%0.2f', $data->productivity)`
which will output 0.72

Answer (score 0):

you can use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to show the format you want:

it Formats a number with grouped thousands and optionally decimal digits.

```
$energy->productivity = $request->input('work_time') / ($request->input('admin_time') + $request->input('driving_time') + $request->input('work_time'));
$energy->productivity=number_format($energy->productivity,2);
```

and you can use it directly in your blade file:

```
<td>{{number_format($data->productivity, 2)}}</td>
```

you can replace '2' with any number you want to show more numbers after the comma.

Comment: Yes use `number_format` as `round` will not show trailing zeros. Example: `"1.50" => "1.5"`. Note that function has 2 extra parameters. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php for full reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>{{round($data->productivity, 2)}}</td>
```

You can try round